# How to remove old file between by which month until which month?

Tags: linux

Any idea how to I remove my old file between by which month until which month, which is using linux command?

example what I want to do is:

```
rm oldfile.txt april until may 2012
```

Any idea how to solve my problem ?

thanks

Comment: I using putty to access server, actually is linux command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A three step process, using `find`:

```
touch -d '2012-04-01 00:00:00' STARTING
touch -d '2012-04-30 23:59:59' STOPPING

find . -type f -newer STARTING -not -newer STOPPING -exec rm {} \;
```

Edit: Note that this will remove files between April and May. Therefore files between the 1st April 2012 and 30th April 2012 will be removed. Also, it's a good idea to view the list of files you'll be deleting before actually deleting them. To do this, change `rm` to `ls -la`.

Answer (score 0):

awk can help you delete files from a single month (or a set of months)

```
ls -l | awk '{if ($6=="Apr" || $6=="Mai") print $9}' | xargs rm
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start by displaying the files and also their last modification time in a date that you can easily recognize using `stat`:

```
$ stat -c '%n %z' foo bar
2012-02-25 23:39:31.000000000 +0000 foo
2012-02-25 23:43:35.000000000 +0000 bar
```

Combine this with `grep` you can filter the list to the months that you want:

```
$ stat -c '%n %z' foo bar | grep -E '^2012-0[45]-.. '
```

Which should give you files that were modified between April and May 2012. Then you'll want to extract only the file name (the fourth field onwards) for deletion using `cut`:

```
$ stat -c '%n %z' foo bar | grep -E '^2012-0[45]-.. ' | cut -f 4- -d' '
```

Once you're satisfied with the output, then delete them like so (this is the point of no return, so put your seatbelt on :):

```
$ !! | while read filename; do rm -f "$filename"; done
```

Note: that `!!` notation repeats the immediate last command so you don't have to type it all over again.  In this case it will repeat the stat command with the final cut at the end.